# How can upload Image on local server

Tags: php

After more 80 times (with use of all hint in this site also) without result. (I work on Debian Server and windows 10)
I do it on Internet but not on local server
my code are as:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
</head>
<body>            
<form action="upload_OneImage.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="file" name="photoU" /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
<?php
$valid_file = NULL;
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    //if they DID upload a file...
    if ($_FILES['photoU']['name']) {
        //if no errors...
        if (!$_FILES['photoU']['error']) {
            //check the size of file and validate it's size
            $new_file_name = strtolower($_FILES['photoU']['name']);
            //change the all the capital letter to lower letter
            echo "file_name= $new_file_name <br />";
            if ($_FILES['photoU']['size'] > (1024000)) { //can't be larger than 1 MB
                $valid_file = FALSE;
                $message    = "Oops!  Your file's size is too large.";
            } else {
                $valid_file = TRUE;
            }
            //if the test was successfull
            if ($valid_file) {
                //move it to directory that name "upload"
                move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"][0], "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"][0]);
                //move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photoU']['tmp_name'], 'upload/' . $new_file_name);
                $message = 'Congratulations!  Your file was accepted.<br />';
            }
        }
        //if there is an error...
        else {
            //set that to be the returned message
            $message = 'Sorry!  Your upload triggered the following error:  ' . $_FILES['photoU']['error'];
        }
    }
    echo "$message ";
}
?>

</body>
</html>
```

I have a directory as "images". It contains the imges. And I have another directory as "upload" to keep the uploads files.
I also want to show the image in small size durring upload.
Can somebody tell me what is problem?

Comment: You are the one who should tell us what the problem is. Then we can help you fix the problem. If you don't know what the problem is, you need to debug your code: check every line of code, every value returned by the functions you call, check what lines of code are run in your `if` blocks.